# Passing user input to external link in django

Tags: html, django, httprequest, django-request

I am trying to create a simple django site that would send information to another site with the
`requests.post` function (I'm assuming that this is a correct method, but maybe there is a better way).

So far I have a simple .html file created using bootstrap

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">text_thing</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text_thing" name="text_thing">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">number_thing</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="number_thing" name="number_thing">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Send data</button>
</form>
```

and my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests

def my_view(requests):
    if requests.method == "POST":
        text_thing=  request.GET.get('text_thing')
        number_thing= request.GET.get('number_thing')
        post_data = {'text_thing', 'number_thing'}
        if text_thing is not None:
            response = requests.post('https://example.com', data=post_data)
            content = reponse.content
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(requests, 'my_view.html', {})
```

I want the site to do following: render itself allowing the user to input something in both fields, and after pressing the button to be redirected to another site - in this case `'home'` and for the input to get sent to `example.com`. With this moment the page renders correctly but after pressing the button nothing happens and external site receives no data.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors in your code that needs to be fixed first

```
...

def my_view(requests):
    if requests.method == "POST":
        # Here is 1, use POST instead
        # text_thing=  request.GET.get('text_thing')
        # number_thing= request.GET.get('number_thing')
        # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

        text_thing = request.POST.get('text_thing', None)
        number_thing = request.POST.get('number_thing', None)
        # Here is 2, you are not creating a dict this way,
        # You are creating a set, put the variables with the keys.
        post_data = {'text_thing': text_thing, 'number_thing': number_thing}
        ....
```

if your site is not receiving any data, check the response from that other site,
to make sure you are calling the right API.

I hope this helped

Comment: I made the changes, unfortunately after clicking the button still nothing happens, I assume even with the wrong API linked I should be redirected to ```'home'``` after clicking the 'Send data' button

Comment: print the response that you receive from that endpoint, to see what is really going on.

Answer (score 1):

There are many typos in your code. You are confusing `requests` with `request`.
You are importing requests module and passing it to `my_view()` which is incorrect.

`my_view()` is a view function which takes a `request` object, not `requests` library.

And also you should be using request.POST to get payload. request.GET returns query params and not payload.

Here's the updated code

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests

def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        text_thing=  request.POST.get('text_thing')
        number_thing= request.POST.get('number_thing')
        post_data = {'text_thing', 'number_thing'}
        if text_thing is not None:
            response = requests.post('https://example.com', data=post_data)
            content = reponse.content
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'my_view.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Radwan Abu-Odeh and @Underoos I managed to get it working. Thank you very much for your help.

Working example:
.html code

```
<form method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">text_thing</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="text_thing" name="text_thing">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">number_thing</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="number_thing" name="number_thing">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Send data</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        text_thing=  request.POST.get('text_thing', None)
        number_thing= request.POST.get('number_thing', None)
        post_data = {'text_thing': text_thing, 'number_thing': number_thing}
        if text_thing is not None:
            response = requests.post('example.com', data=post_data)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'my_view.html', {})
```